# How to count rows and columns of a .dta file in Stata?

Tags: dataset, stata

I  want to know how to calculate in Stata the total number of columns and rows in a .dta or dataset.

For example, in R language, I know there are two commands "nrow" and "ncol", which returns the number of columns and rows in a dataset. The "dim" command gives the dimensions of the table.

Can anyone please help me what command I should use?

Edit 1: There is a command to count the number of observations (rows), i.e. `count`. I guess there might be a command to give me number of variables (columns).

Edit 2: I am terribly sorry for causing such ruckus over something simple. I found the command finally. It was basically a function `di c(k)` that returns the row numbers. My apologies.

Comment: I actually did google it. Pretty much for like 1 day. Used a number of words to see if it would give any different result. But, unfortunately, It didn't. Their documentation does not have any sort of command like that.

Comment: `di` meaning `display` is strictly a command, not a function. In Stata commands and functions are not synonymous or identical.

Comment: There is an enormous difference between your failing to find out what you want and being confident that it does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

A plain

```
describe
```

gives this information. See also the results of

```
creturn list
```

The number of observations is also accessible as `_N`.